# How do I wait for completion of operations using the Java 7 Files API?

Tags: java, nio

I'm writing some java code that creates a directory and then puts some files in that directory. I don't care about the order in which the files are created, however, for the files to be successfully created the directory needs to exit first.

I want to use the (newish) [java.nio.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) api as it has quite an elegant set of methods for working with files and directories.

While it's nice that the `Files` class is non-blocking it means that the directory doesn't always exist. Is there a "right" way to determine when the `Files.createDirectories(path)` has completed?

Not particularly complex (which is why I like the Files api) but here's some sample code:

```
Files.createDirectories(path);
Files.write(filename1, "some content".getBytes());
Files.write(filename2, "some other content".getBytes());
```

In the above `path` might be `/tmp/blah` and `filename1` = `/tmp/blah/foo` and `filename2` = `/tmp/blah/bar`.

Obviously I can do this using some other class or library (like Commons IO) but the build in java.nio.Files is quite nice.

Comment: Based on your example code, you might be interested in [`Files.writeString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) (Java 11+).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood. Those operations are actually synchronous, so you're good to go here. `Files.write` uses a `java.io.OutputStream` for example.

*Some Name* addressed the possible implementation of `createDirectory` for Linux.
On Windows, `createDirectory` uses the [CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createdirectory) WinAPI function.

```
WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateDirectory(var3.getPathForWin32Calls(), var4.address() /* Security descriptor */);
```

`Buffers`, `Channels` and `Selectors` are *non-blocking*.

Comment: Yep, I've just figured out what I was doing wrong. I slept on it last night and couldn't see it until I described the problem here. Clearly I need to buy a rubber duck (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @grahamrb hahaha well that happens ;)

Comment: Writing to regular files is blocking anyway.

Comment: @SomeName yes. I added a reference to the WinAPI function that gets called, on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. The issue wasn't actually with the non-blocking nature of the Files class. I was mixing File objects and Path objects and converting between them and java seemed to get confused with what a directory and a file was and instead created files that were called `blah/foo` and `blah/bar` instead of a file calls `foo` in a folder called `blah`. I've just switched to pass Path objects around instead of File objects to represent my files and directories and all is working.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a "right" way to determine when the 
>   Files.createDirectories(path) has completed

As soon as it returns it is completed. It is higly likely that this is a simple wrapper of `mkdir(2)`

Moreover Non-blocking semantic has no effect on regular files (at least in Linux and at least now) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

> O_NONBLOCK or O_NDELAY
>
> [...]
>
> Note that this flag has no effect for regular files and 
>   block devices; that is, I/O operations will (briefly) block 
>   when device activity is required, regardless of whether 
>   O_NONBLOCK is set.